# How to filter by Regex in LibreOffice?

Tags: regex, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I've got this string:

```
{"success":true,"lowest_price":"1,49€","volume":"1,132","median_price":"1,49€"}
```

Now I want the value for median_price being displayed in a cell. HHow can I achive this with Regex?

With regex101.com I've came to this solution:

```
(?<=median_price":")\d{0,4},\d{2}€
```

But this one does not seem to be working in LibreOffice calc.

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise to discard the Euro-symbol at first since you'd probably want to retrieve a value to calculate with, a numeric value. Therefor try:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=--REGEX(A1;".*median_price"":""(\d+(?:,\d+)?)€.*";"$1")
```

The double unary will transform the result from the 1st capture group into a number. I then went ahead and formatted the cell to display currency (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>).

---

**Note:** I went with a slightly different regular pattern. But go with whatever works for your data I supppose.